# Interpreting results of the vegan anova.cca function

Tags: anova, canonical-correlation, vegan

1st question here!

I've scoured the internet, including the vegan documentation, but am still confused about the meaning of the F versus ChiSquare values in the results of the anova.cca() vegan function.  In this scenario, I've sampled the microbiome of 15 animals over several months and want to know which variable contributes the most to changes in diversity- age or individuality (animal ID).  In every example I can find online the ChiSquare and F value are always the highest for one variable, but in my results ChiSquare is highest for "animalID" and the F is highest for "Age" and both are significant.  I would like to know a) in layman's terms, the meaning of each value, b) which variable is more influential in this case and c) which should be reported in a manuscript (both?).  Thank you!

```
#R code:
my.cca <- ordinate(animal_microbiome, "CCA",formula = otu_matrix ~ Age*AnimalID*Sex*Abx, scaling=2)
anova.cca(my.cca, by="terms") 

#Output:
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: cca(formula = OTU ~ Age * AnimalID * Sex * Abx, data = data)
          Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)    
Age        1    0.4673 7.7879  0.001 ***
Name      14    2.1805 2.5958  0.001 ***
Age:Name  14    1.9529 2.3248  0.001 ***
Residual 169   10.1400                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on degrees of freedom (Df). In general, the F (that I rather call pseudo-F) is calculated as ChiSquare_term/Df_term/(ChiSquare_Residual/Df_Residual). For Age this is (0.4673/1)/(10.14/169) and for Name (2.1885/14)/(10.14/169).

I don't know any rigorously correct way of saying which variable is more  influential. Some people use ChiSquare and call the proportion of ChiSquare_term/ChiSquare_total as R squared, but personally I won't do so. If you fit a model with these terms, you should report a model with these terms in your manuscript. CCA is nothing but a kind of multivariate linear model with Chi-square quirks, and the same rules apply as reporting linear models (`lm` in **R**).